# Switch encendido y apagado

Tags: arduino

Tengo un problema y es que necesito hacer un switch o interruptor de encender y apagar una bombilla. 
Yo estoy manejando un ciclo que me indica que mientras el estado del switch sea igual a 1 (encendido) entonces que me encienda la bombilla. 
El problema es que no sé cómo pararlo.
La bombilla inicia apagada, cuando oprimo el interruptor, enciende la bombilla, pero cuando lo vuelvo a oprimir, no apaga. 
Acá el código:

```
//  CODIGO

/* Pulsador controlando el encendido y apagado de un led */

// Declaración de variables

const int led = 12;         // Pin 12 asignado a un LED
int pulsador = 2;           // Pin 2 asignado a un pulsador

int estado = 0;             // Variable con la que leeremos el estado del pulsador 
int estadoActual = 0;       // Variable que puedo usar como contador

// Configuración
void setup()
    {
    pinMode(pulsador, INPUT); // Ponemos el pulsador como entrada
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     // Configuramos el LED como salida (para las entradas no hace falta)
    }

// Bucle
void loop()
    {
    estado = digitalRead(pulsador); //Leemos el estado del pulsador (0 o 1) y asignamos el valor a la variable "estado"
    if(estadoActual <> 0)           //Si el estado actual es diferente de 0 arranca el contador
        {

        }


    while(estado == 1)              //Mientras el pulsador está activado (estado = 1) encienda la bombilla
        {
        digitalWrite(led, HIGH);    //Se enciende el LED
        delay(pulsador);            //Va a tener el tiempo hasta que el pulsador cambie

        }
    if(estado == 0)                 //Si
        {
        digitalWrite(led, LOW);     //Se apaga el LED
        delay(1000);                //Va a tener el tiempo hasta que el pulsador cambie
        pulsador = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el estado es igual a 1, tu programa nunca va a salir del ciclo `while` ya que nunca actualizas la variable `estado` dentro de este, por lo que este se convierte en un ciclo infinito y nunca se ejecuta el código que le sigue, por eso no apaga el led.

Intenta con un ciclo similar a este:

```
while (estado == 1) {         //Mientras el pulsador está activado
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);    //Se enciende el LED
    estado = digitalRead(pulsador);
    delay(pulsador);  
}
```

Comment: No, sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: ¿Cómo funciona el interruptor que tienes? ¿es on/off o manda un pulso cada vez que lo oprimes?

Comment: jachguate, si, se supone que es un interruptor. On/off, cuando yo lo encienda, que quede prendido hasta que yo le dé la orden de off o apagado.

Answer (score 0):

Al final pones

```
pulsador = 0;
```

Estas modificando el pin de entrada al próximo ciclo leerá el pin 0, no deberías modificar esa variable.

```
void loop()
{
  estado = digitalRead(pulsador); //Leemos el estado del pulsador (0 o 1) y asignamos el valor a la variable "estado"
  if(estado == 1)              //Mientras el pulsador está activado (estado = 1) encienda la bombilla
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);    //Se enciende el LED

  }
  else if(estado == 0)                 //Si
  {
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);     //Se apaga el LED
  }
}
```

O más simple:

```
void loop()
{
  estado = digitalRead(pulsador); //Leemos el estado del pulsador (0 o 1) y asignamos el valor a la variable "estado"
  digitalWrite(led, estado);
}
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, la verdad sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: ¿como tienes el circuito? debería ser así: https://www.luisllamas.es/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/arduino-pulsador-3.png o cambia la linea `pinMode(pulsador, INPUT);` por `pinMode(pulsador, INPUT_PULLUP);` si no quieres modificar el circuito. El código que puse es para interruptor, no para pulsador. (con un pulsador se prenderia el led solo cuando se mantiene presionado)